# PHP-Apache in Docker with only one request in the same time

Tags: php, apache, docker

This is my Dockerfile for dev enviroment:

```
FROM php:5.6-apache

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get upgrade -y \
    && apt-get install -y -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confold" \
    libapache2-mod-php5 \
    php5-mysql \
    php5-cgi \
    php5-curl \
    php5-sqlite \
    php5-gd \
    wget \
    gdebi \
    php5-xdebug \
 && apt-get clean \
 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN a2enmod rewrite
RUN service apache2 restart
```

If I try open two or more tabs in Google Chrome pointing the same url `http://localhost/myweb` (docker), each tab wait that previous tab finish load for start new request. Its like Apache can't process more that one request in the same time.

How its possible fix this problem?

**Edit 2016.03.08**

Host OS: Debian Jessie

I run with this docker-compose.yml:

```
...
myserver-php:
 build: ./dockerfile
 container_name: myserver-php
 volumes:
  - ./var_log_apache2:/var/log/apache2
  - ./etc_apache2_sitesavailable:/etc/apache2/sites-available
  - ./tmp:/tmp
  - ./git:/var/www/html
 ports:
  - "80:80"
 links:
  - myserver-mysql
  - myserver-redis
  - myserver-sphinx
  - myserver-elastic
...
```

Comment: Can you please confirm your host OS and how you are launching the container?

Comment: Thanks Andy. I edit my original post.

Comment: Do you use PHP sessions?

Comment: What Stefan is getting at above (+1) is that sessions are blocking by default. Try <?php sleep(5+(integer)$_GET['sleep']); ?> or use more than one browser.

Comment: Thanks Stefan and symcbean. I read about this topic in http://konrness.com/php5/how-to-prevent-blocking-php-requests/, and yes, this is my problem. Finally wasn't problem of docker, only php workflow.